# Trouble with CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName()

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I have been trying to create CGGlyph with CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName() method. It is working for all letters, but no for numbers.

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, true);
    CGContextSetFont(ctx, font);
    CGContextSetFontSize(ctx, size);
    CGGlyph glyph = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("L"));
    CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(ctx, &glyph, &(textbounds.origin), 1);
}
```

[Windows shows L letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlbVa.png)

And when I am trying to draw number it does not work:

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, true);
    CGContextSetFont(ctx, font);
    CGContextSetFontSize(ctx, size);
    CGGlyph glyph = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("3"));
    CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(ctx, &glyph, &(textbounds.origin), 1);
}
```

[Window shows empty rect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnE30.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glyph for “3” is probably named `three` (spelled out).  Here's my test:

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

let font = CGFont("Helvetica" as CFString)!
for g in CGGlyph.min ... CGGlyph.max {
    if let name = font.name(for: g) {
        print("\(g) \(name)")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
... many lines omitted ....
17 period
18 slash
19 zero
20 one
21 two
22 three
23 four
24 five
25 six
26 seven
... many more lines omitted ...
```

You might be better off using the Core Text `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters` function. Note that it uses a `CTFontRef`, not a `CGFontRef`. You can convert a `CGFontRef` to a `CTFontRef` using `CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont`.